# Connect to Kafka through SOCKS Proxy

Tags: java, proxy, jvm, apache-kafka, socks

I have a Kafka cluster running on AWS. I want to connect to the cluster with the standard *kafka-console-consumer* from my application server. The application server has access to the internet via a SOCKS-Proxy. No authentication is required

How do I tell the Kafka client to connect through the proxy?

I tried many things, including adding the standard JVM Proxy parameters to the *kaka-run-class.sh* script. But I still get a *connection refused* error.

```
exec $JAVA -DsocksProxyHost=proxy.host.name -DsocksProxyPort=1080 $KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS $KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS $KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS $KAFKA_JMX_OPTS $KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS -cp $CLASSPATH $KAFKA_OPTS "$@"
```

**Edit:**
It turns out, Kafka uses the java.nio library. It's socket implementation is not compatible with proxies. So the jvm parameters I used have no effect on the Kafka client.

Comment: did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @StasKolodyuk See the edit. Due to Kafka's usage of java.nio, tunnelling through a SOCKS-Proxy is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment and edit, the asker already found the solution/root cause:

> It turns out, Kafka uses the java.nio library. It's socket
> implementation is not compatible with proxies. So the jvm parameters I
> used have no effect on the Kafka client.