# Is there a way to configure a KafkaConsumer (apache.kafka.kafka-clients) to work with Kafka brokers via proxy?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, proxy

I'm using a KafkaConsumer java client to connect with Kafka brokers.
My user can define a proxy (ip : port) between the KafkaConsumer and the brokers.

```
----------------------         -------------         -----------------------
| Application client |  <--->  | TCP Proxy |  <--->  | Target (e.g. kafka) |
----------------------         -------------         -----------------------
```

Without the proxy, configuration 'boostrap.servers' with the broker's list is enough to establish an initial connection.

My question is, **how can I manage the KafkaConsumer to initial the connection with the brokers via the proxy?** does apache-Kafka have that kind of support?

I tried to find a property such as '`listeners`' and '`advertised.listeners`', however, they are a broker configuration and I **can't** configure the brokers.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47570246/connect-to-kafka-through-socks-proxy seems to imply that creating a socks proxy would be a challenge, so you're left with @cricket_007 's suggestion -- Kafka REST proxy.

Answer (score 1):

The TCP protocol would need to establish a socket handshake, then request events from upstream Kafka then forward back as a streaming response to the requesting client....

If building a TCP protocol is too much for you, then you could use the KAFKA REST Proxy instead.

Alternatively, clarify why you cannot directly connect to any broker